# New to python - working on nested loops. I am trying to draw 4 squares from turtle import but code only draws 1

Tags: python, nested, nested-loops

I hope someone can enlighten me on this one! I am very, very new to python and can't get my head around this one! Can you please help/explain...

I believe the following code should draw 4 squares in a row. This exercise is to learn nested loops. What it seems to be doing is to draw 4 squares on the same spot without moving forward to draw them next to each other on the same line.

```py
# Draw Squares across page
from turtle import *
number_of_shapes = 4

for number_of_shapes in range(1, number_of_shapes + 1) :
# Draw a Square
 for sides in range (1, 5) :
        forward (40)
        right (90)

# Move forward to start of next square
penup ()
forward (50)
pendown ()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works. Is there something wrong with your indentation?

```
#Draw Squares across page
from turtle import * 
number_of_shapes = 4

for number_of_shapes in range(1, number_of_shapes + 1):

    #Draw a Square
    for sides in range(1, 5): 
        forward(40) 
        right(90)

    #Move forward to start of next square
    penup() 
    forward(50) 
    pendown()
```

My guess is that your code was this:

```
#Draw Squares across page
from turtle import * 
number_of_shapes = 4

for number_of_shapes in range(1, number_of_shapes + 1):

    #Draw a Square
    for sides in range(1, 5): 
        forward(40) 
        right(90)

        #Move forward to start of next square
        penup() 
        forward(50) 
        pendown()
```

So rather than drawing the square and then moving, you're drawing a line and then moving.

Comment: Please format your code properly in your question, whitespace is significant in python so it's impossible for us to tell what your code is doing.

Comment: Hi! thanks for helping and clarifying this for me. It works now! I will format the code properly next time as I will definitely be asking questions on here again. I really appreciate your swift response. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution you wrote looks fine, maybe there is a problem with indentation which is most important in Python because it present code blocks like other languages do with {}. Another thing is, that your are using number_of_shapes in the first loop as iteration variable which can cause a problem since the loop save the number (1, 2, 3, 4, ...) to this variable. You can try how it works in a simple loop.

```
for x in range(1, 5):
    print(x)
```

Try to change this to some different variable (`for x in range(1, number_of_shapes + 1):`) or some developers, if they don't need to use this variable in they code, they just use `_`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think it was purely an issue with indentation. I really appreciate your time in answering.